# Answer not matching for $\dfrac{\pi^2}{10}\int_{-10}^{10}f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx$ for the following definition of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For any real number $x$, let $\left[x\right]$ denote the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on the interval $[–10, 10] $ by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x-\left[x\right], &\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
1+\left[x\right]-x, &\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

Evaluate $\dfrac{\pi^2}{10}\int_{-10}^{10}f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx$

My attempt is as follows:-

If $x\in Z$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, &x \text { is odd }\\
1, &x \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

If $x\notin Z$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\{x\}, &\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
1-\{x\}, &\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

**Let's see if $f(x)$ is odd or even**

For $x\in Z$, one can easily see $f(x)$ is even

For $x\notin Z$, we will have to check

$$f(-x)=\begin{cases}
\{-x\}, &\left[-x\right] \text { is odd }\\
1-\{-x\}, &\left[-x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$\{x\}+\{-x\}=1$$
$$\left[x\right]+\left[-x\right]=-1$$

$$f(-x)=\begin{cases}
1-\{x\}, &-1-\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
\{x\}, &-1-\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(-x)=\begin{cases}
1-\{x\}, &-1-\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
\{x\}, &-1-\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(-x)=\begin{cases}
1-\{x\}, &-\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\{x\}, &-\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(-x)=\begin{cases}
1-\{x\}, &\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\{x\}, &\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(-x)=f(x)$$

Now before applying the even-odd property of definite integral, we should check the continuity of function at integers

**Let's check continuity at $x=2n$**

$$f(2n)=1$$
$$f(2n^{+})=\lim_{x\to2n^{+}}1-\{x\}=1$$
$$f(2n^{-})=\lim_{x\to2n^{-}}\{x\}=1$$

**Let's check continuity at $x=2n+1$**

$$f(2n+1)=0$$
$$f((2n+1)^{+})=\lim_{x\to2n+1^{+}}\{x\}=0$$
$$f((2n+1)^{+})=\lim_{x\to2n+1^{+}}1-\{x\}=0$$

So it is continuous also at integers.

Hence $\dfrac{\pi^2}{10}\int_{-10}^{10}f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx$ can be written as

$$\dfrac{\pi^2}{5}\int_{0}^{10}f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx$$

Let's find $f(10-x)$

For $x\in Z$, one can easily see $f(x)=f(10-x)$

For $x\notin Z$

$$f(10-x)=\begin{cases}
\{10-x\}, &\left[10-x\right] \text { is odd }\\
1-\{10-x\}, &\left[10-x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(10-x)=\begin{cases}
\{-x\}, &10+\left[-x\right] \text { is odd }\\
1-\{-x\}, &10+\left[-x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(10-x)=\begin{cases}
1-\{x\}, &\left[-x\right] \text { is odd }\\
\{x\}, &\left[-x\right] \text { is even }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(10-x)=\begin{cases}
1-\{x\}, &\left[x\right] \text { is even }\\
\{x\}, &\left[x\right] \text { is odd }\\
\end{cases}$$

$$f(10-x)=f(x)$$

So $f(10-x)\cos\pi(10-x)=f(x)\cos(\pi x)$, hence integral can be written $\dfrac{2\pi^2}{5}\int_{0}^{5}f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx$

So now again checking for $f(5-x)$

$5$ would not behave different from $10$, so $f(5-x)=f(x)$ , but $\cos\pi(5-x)=\cos(5\pi-\pi x)=-\cos\pi x$

So $f(5-x)\cos\pi(5-x)=-f(x)\cos(\pi x)$

hence $\dfrac{2\pi^2}{5}\int_{0}^{5}f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx=0$

But actual answer is $4$, what am I missing here?

Comment: Won't the even and odd swap now? So 5 behaves differently than 10, since the fact that $10 + [-x]$ being even implies $[-x] $ being even implicilty relies on 10 being even

Comment: yeah you are correct. Let me correct it.